# Can't set programmatically created UITextField text to UIPickerView value

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitextfield, uipickerview

I've created a `UITextField` programmatically (`myTextField : UITextField!`) so I can easily control its attributes.

I want to be able to set its text to the selected value of a UIPicker (programmatically created via `myPickerView: UIPickerView! = UIPickerView()`), but whenever I try `myTextField.text = pickerData[row]` inside `didSelectRow`the app crashes saying nil was found while unwrapping an Optional.

I'm using `myTextField.inputView = myPickerView` which behaves properly and I can successfully print out the selected row from the picker view. It's only when I try to set the text that it crashes.

When I set up a button on the storyboard as an IBOutlet it works properly, but I want to avoid using storyboard. Is there anyway around this? Or is it possible to style a storyboard button programmatically?

UPDATE: I've set a tag to `myTextField` and set `myTextField.text` using the tag under the pickers `didSelect` protocol, but that feels roundabout and hacky

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your textfield is nil. You need to initialize the textField before using the pickerView. Best method is

```
myTextField = UITextField()
myTextField.inputView = myPickerView
```

So that, the pickerView appears only when you touch the textField. If you want it to be open by default, use

```
myTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: I already set up the code where `myTextField : UITextField!` is before `myTextField.inputView = myPickerView`. That's been working for me. The problem isn't that the picker doesn't appear, but rather that the app crashes when scrolling the picker and trying to set `myTextField.text`. I've set a tag to the text field and set `myTextField.text` using the tag, but that feels roundabout and hacky

Comment: The one that I've set the tag for? Yes

Comment: maybe that textfield is set to nil in some other code, try debugging if your textfield is nil in your didSelectRow

Answer (score -1):

I think you didn't initialize the textfield before setting the text.